# I get a "The executed contract exhausted its gas limit." when attempting to instantiate a contract

Tags: substrate-contracts-node, cargo-contract

I am new to substrate.  Am trying to deploy and instantiate a simple contract on a local node.  Everything is via the command line (cargo), or node.js, no UI, no browser.

Am using [paritytech's substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) because it already comes with contracts-pallet, and [substrate-developer-hub's substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) does not seem to.

I create a simple project: `cargo contract new flipper`.

Then, `cargo +nightly contract build --release`.

Then, I make sure the node is running:

```
substrate-contracts-node --dev --detailed-log-output
```

(I don't think  I even need any options).

Then, `cargo contract upload --verbose --suri //Alice` .

Output on client-side:

```
$ cargo contract upload --verbose --suri //Alice
VERBOSE
        Event Balances ➜ Withdraw
          who: 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
          amount: 525756416
        Event Balances ➜ Reserved
          who: 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
          amount: 314475000000
        Event Contracts ➜ CodeStored
          code_hash: 0x4406fe2cdb0473a8925be201d3452ce15a0988406c7eb4fb48a6ca324bac2733
        Event TransactionPayment ➜ TransactionFeePaid
          who: 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
          actual_fee: 525756416
          tip: 0
        Event System ➜ ExtrinsicSuccess
          dispatch_info: DispatchInfo { weight: 439457000, class: Normal, pays_fee: Yes }

    Code hash 0x4406fe2cdb0473a8925be201d3452ce15a0988406c7eb4fb48a6ca324bac2733
```

I use the code hash for the instantiate command:

```
code_hash=0x4406fe2cdb0473a8925be201d3452ce15a0988406c7eb4fb48a6ca324bac2733;

cargo contract instantiate \
    --verbose \
    --constructor new \
    --suri //Alice \
    --code-hash $code_hash
```

Output client side:

```
ERROR: Module error: Contracts: OutOfGas

The executed contract exhausted its gas limit.
```

The output on the terminal running the node: (deploy):

```
2022-07-29 00:14:17  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x2f9fcaae0e2c09157198db93ab7d30c0251d033203604f730a06f9bfd1a285df
2022-07-29 00:14:17  Prepared block for proposing at 11 (4 ms) [hash: 0x5e9b43d696429a702669b92b50ec21ff6e5f1b68d52c30bf8a4180d023a449be; parent_hash: 0x2f9f…85df; extrinsics (2): [0x238c…aa21, 0xc325…d77b]]
2022-07-29 00:14:17 Instant Seal success: CreatedBlock { hash: 0x5e9b43d696429a702669b92b50ec21ff6e5f1b68d52c30bf8a4180d023a449be, aux: ImportedAux { header_only: false, clear_justification_requests: false, needs_justification: false, bad_justification: false, is_new_best: true } }
2022-07-29 00:14:17 ✨ Imported #11 (0x5e9b…49be)
```

Node terminal ouput: (instantiate):

```
2022-07-29 00:16:04 Accepting new connection, 1/100
2022-07-29 00:16:04  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x5e9b43d696429a702669b92b50ec21ff6e5f1b68d52c30bf8a4180d023a449be
2022-07-29 00:16:04  Prepared block for proposing at 12 (0 ms) [hash: 0x24704f81396e053fc4861656dee410a52cad8203900ae99ef89c03795f9f5178; parent_hash: 0x5e9b…49be; extrinsics (2): [0x64cf…1ada, 0xf68f…52bd]]
2022-07-29 00:16:04 Instant Seal success: CreatedBlock { hash: 0x24704f81396e053fc4861656dee410a52cad8203900ae99ef89c03795f9f5178, aux: ImportedAux { header_only: false, clear_justification_requests: false, needs_justification: false, bad_justification: false, is_new_best: true } }
2022-07-29 00:16:04 ✨ Imported #12 (0x2470…5178)
```

So now what? I think my use of `cargo contract` is out as far as "gas" is concerned.

Willing to write up a node.js client (`@polkadot/api`), but not sure how to proceed. Who needs the "gas"... the contract?  If so, how do I get a reference/id/address to it?

Should that have happened during deployment, during instantiation? Are the starting default values for `//Alice` too little?

I am not clear as to the exact problem, thus how to solve it.

**UPDATE:**

Thank you to Alexander Theißen, I think I got past the original "gas limit" problem.

I am still not quite sure if I have all of the correct parameters for the `cargo contract instantiate` command.

Here is what I have:

```
code_hash=0x4406fe2cdb0473a8925be201d3452ce15a0988406c7eb4fb48a6ca324bac2733
    cargo contract instantiate \
        --verbose \
        --storage-deposit-limit 50000000000 \
        --gas 50000000000 \
        --constructor new \
        --args false \
        --suri //Alice \
        --code-hash $code_hash
```

The error is:

```
ERROR: Rpc error: JSON-RPC call failed: RPC Call failed: code: 1002, message: Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Error calling api function: Failed to convert parameter `tx` from node to runtime of validate_transaction, data: Some(RawValue("RuntimeApi(\"Execution failed: Error calling api function: Failed to convert parameter `tx` from node to runtime of validate_transaction\")"))

Caused by:
    0: JSON-RPC call failed: RPC Call failed: code: 1002, message: Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Error calling api function: Failed to convert parameter `tx` from node to runtime of validate_transaction, data: Some(RawValue("RuntimeApi(\"Execution failed: Error calling api function: Failed to convert parameter `tx` from node to runtime of validate_transaction\")"))
    1: RPC Call failed: code: 1002, message: Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Error calling api function: Failed to convert parameter `tx` from node to runtime of validate_transaction, data: Some(RawValue("RuntimeApi(\"Execution failed: Error calling api function: Failed to convert parameter `tx` from node to runtime of validate_transaction\")"))
```

However, if I use a UI: [https://paritytech.github.io/contracts-ui](https://ERROR:%20Rpc%20error:%20JSON-RPC%20call%20failed:%20RPC%20Call%20failed:%20code:%201002,%20message:%20Verification%20Error:%20Runtime%20error:%20Execution%20failed:%20Error%20calling%20api%20function:%20Failed%20to%20convert%20parameter%20%60tx%60%20from%20node%20to%20runtime%20of%20validate_transaction,%20data:%20Some(RawValue(%22RuntimeApi(%5C%22Execution%20failed:%20Error%20calling%20api%20function:%20Failed%20to%20convert%20parameter%20%60tx%60%20from%20node%20to%20runtime%20of%20validate_transaction%5C%22)%22))%20%20Caused%20by:%20%20%20%20%200:%20JSON-RPC%20call%20failed:%20RPC%20Call%20failed:%20code:%201002,%20message:%20Verification%20Error:%20Runtime%20error:%20Execution%20failed:%20Error%20calling%20api%20function:%20Failed%20to%20convert%20parameter%20%60tx%60%20from%20node%20to%20runtime%20of%20validate_transaction,%20data:%20Some(RawValue(%22RuntimeApi(%5C%22Execution%20failed:%20Error%20calling%20api%20function:%20Failed%20to%20convert%20parameter%20%60tx%60%20from%20node%20to%20runtime%20of%20validate_transaction%5C%22)%22))%20%20%20%20%201:%20RPC%20Call%20failed:%20code:%201002,%20message:%20Verification%20Error:%20Runtime%20error:%20Execution%20failed:%20Error%20calling%20api%20function:%20Failed%20to%20convert%20parameter%20%60tx%60%20from%20node%20to%20runtime%20of%20validate_transaction,%20data:%20Some(RawValue(%22RuntimeApi(%5C%22Execution%20failed:%20Error%20calling%20api%20function:%20Failed%20to%20convert%20parameter%20%60tx%60%20from%20node%20to%20runtime%20of%20validate_transaction%5C%22)%22))), I can connect to the local `substrate-contracts-node` and even just use the uploaded contract by supplying the UI with code_hash.  From there I can successfully make calls to the contract.

So I assume the issue is related to something I am doing wrong with the `cargo contract instantiate` parameters.

Comment: I'm hitting the same problem...did you manage to get a contract deployed & instantiated using cargo contract?

Comment: @csknk, it's been a while, but I think i was successful..  try this page i wrote up:  https://github.com/elicorrales/my-first-substrate-project-series-III-part-5

Comment: The article you linked to is very useful - thanks

Answer (score 3):

Every contract execution whether it is an instantiation or a call needs to set a parameter named [`gas_limit`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/3ca8a42954e284bfb8771ed93d37cced3a7809b9/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L537) to cap how much execution it is allowed to perform. This is necessary because whoever sends a transaction needs to pay for its execution and without this limit the costs would be uncapped.

In your case you didn't supply `--gas` which makes `cargo contract` use its default of `50_000_000_000` which is apparently not enough. To find out how much you need you can run your command with `--dry-run` first which returns the gas required. In case of a dry run you don't pay any fees. So you can just supply a very high `--gas` in order to find out how much you actually need.