# How to use the Builders Approach in the basic-contract-caller example without using the Contract References approach?

Tags: ink, cross-contract-call, basic-contract-caller, contract-references-approach

This question is an extension of [this previous question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/q/8901/83) where [this commit of this Pull Request](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/commits/ed4290e1fc13624388bd97a2fcee9c4f1a3296d0) I used a modified version of this [ink! basic-contract-caller example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/basic_contract_caller) where there is a `BasicContractCaller` main contract and a `OtherContract` sub-contract.

But this question relates to changes I made to that code by using the **Builders approach** section's `CreateBuilder` and `CallBuilder` as mentioned in the ink! documentation [here](https://use.ink/basics/cross-contract-calling#builders).

The Builder approach that I implemented is in [this commit](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/commits/455c222c08127f461b2f23897ead1663a9e1d927).

To run it, I follow the steps in the [README file](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/blob/unnamed/README.md#setup-docker-container-) and then after entering the Docker container I run `cd /app && ./docker/quickstart-basic-contract-caller.sh` and it runs through these steps:

0. Starts a fresh local node using substrate-contracts-node
1. Builds both of those contracts
2. Uploads both of those contracts
3. Instantiates both of those contracts with
   `cargo contract instantiate --manifest-path $PARENT_DIR/dapps/basic_contract_caller/Cargo.toml --suri //Alice --constructor new --args $CODE_HASH_SUB $CONTRACT_ADDR_SUB --execute --gas 200000000000 --proof-size 100000000000 --skip-confirm`.
   Note: It was necessary to provide more gas `--gas 200000000000` otherwise I got error [`The executed contract exhausted its gas limit`](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3992/i-get-a-the-executed-contract-exhausted-its-gas-limit-when-attempting-to-inst).
   Note: It was also necessary to use `.endowment(0)`, otherwise I got error [`Cross-contract instantiation failed with TransferFailed`](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8445/cross-contract-instantiation-failed-with-transferfailed/8447#8447).
4. Calls a setter method `flip()` in the sub-contract directly `cargo contract call --suri //Alice --contract $CONTRACT_ADDR_SUB --message get --execute --gas 200000000000 --proof-size 100000000000 --skip-confirm`
5. Calls a getter method `get()` in the sub-contract directly with `cargo contract call --suri //Alice --contract $CONTRACT_ADDR_SUB --message get --execute --skip-confirm`
6. Calls a method `get()` in the main contract that calls a getter method `get()` in the sub-contract `cargo contract call --suri //Alice --contract $CONTRACT_ADDR_MAIN --message get --execute --skip-confirm`.

Based on that ink! documentation I thought it was necessary to remove use of Contract Ref from the Contract References Approach if I was going to use the Builder approach instead, however I was not able remove having to import the sub-contract that I want to call as a dependency of the main contract since in the documentation [here](https://use.ink/basics/cross-contract-calling#createbuilder) it seems necessary to provide the Contract Ref in the Builder Approach implementation example like this `build_create::<OtherContractRef>()`.

Whilst I was able to get the above steps 0-5 to work, I wasn't able to solve the [previous question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8901/why-cant-i-still-directly-call-method-in-sub-contract-of-basic-contract-caller), and **I got errors running step 6**, which calls the sub-contract via the main contract, since it outputs:

```bash
Calling contract method get ...
ERROR: Pre-submission dry-run failed. Use --skip-dry-run to skip this step.
```

And I then ran it with `--skip-dry-run` as the error suggests I do by adding these additional options [here](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/commits/455c222c08127f461b2f23897ead1663a9e1d927#diff-5b2787966dfcd6f68c1db89beb454f6113e3d519c12c149f8cc6ebb36e2e48a3R183):

```
    --gas 200000000000
    --proof-size 100000000000
    --skip-dry-run
```

then instead it outputs the below error, which based on [this question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7457/contracttrapped-transfer-from-calleetrapped), which indicates that a panic has occurred, but in that `get()` method in the main contract [here](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/commits/455c222c08127f461b2f23897ead1663a9e1d927#diff-84af1add043372bf3be8123a2d3477b5f1d436cc0dbbf322c0bcd3c99249adb2R67) I feel like I'm already handling errors appropriately, and the `get()` method it should call in the sub-contract is basic as shown [here](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/files#diff-16556624fa5972a5348e9b062eb7965d702c694b78d5190aa7097dc66d70a79bR28).

```bash
Calling contract method get ...
ERROR: ModuleError: Contracts::ContractTrapped: ["Contract trapped during execution."]
```

**How would I fully remove using Contracts Ref now that I'm using the Builders Approach incase that is the cause of the error??**

Note: Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to debug using this Builder Approach though. They highlight this limitation in the ink! documentation *You will not be able to get any feedback about this at at compile time. You will only find out your call failed at runtime!*.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think resolving the error `ContractTrapped` needs Contracts Ref to be fully removed when using the Builders Approach.

I tried using `try_invoke()` instead of `invoke()` [here](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/commits/e5f449ad44479cc7a1afd70494eda010eaf96123#diff-84af1add043372bf3be8123a2d3477b5f1d436cc0dbbf322c0bcd3c99249adb2R80) as suggested in the ink! documentation [here](https://use.ink/basics/cross-contract-calling#builder-error-handling) and that improved feedback at compile time. Instead of the previous error `ContractTrapped` that was not helpful, it gave the error shown below that suggested it was transfer related:

```
DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::contracts: Execution finished with debug buffer: my_return_value Err(TransferFailed)
error TransferFailed
```

So in the main contract I changing it from `.transferred_value(10)` to `.transferred_value(0)` and that resolved the `TransferFailed` error.

I only used `.transferred_value(10)` because they use that non-zero value in the CallBuilder example [here](https://use.ink/basics/cross-contract-calling/#callbuilder), but I do not know how it is possible to get a non-zero value to work.

I was only able to get it to work using a value of `0` in `.transferred_value(0)`, but not with any larger number, even if I added `payable` in my code [here](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/commits/e5f449ad44479cc7a1afd70494eda010eaf96123#diff-16556624fa5972a5348e9b062eb7965d702c694b78d5190aa7097dc66d70a79bR23) or with `#[ink(message, payable)]` to the `flip()` method in the sub-contract that I was calling via the main contract, as mentioned in the ink! documentation [here](https://use.ink/macros-attributes/payable).